# DIY Ronin 4d-like camera rig with a Micro studio camera G2

Tags: stabilisation, blackmagic, diy, electronics

I've been looking into making a compact camera rig with 4-axis stabilization in the style of a Ronin 4D. I plan to use a Black Magic Micro Studio Camera 4k G2 along with a smaller gimbal that will be attached to a stabilizer arm that should be around 5-6 inches long. The total weight of the camera rig at the end of the arm will be approximately 35 oz. My main issue was finding an electronic 4th-axis with little information on the topic. Is this arm something that is worth trying to make myself, or would a spring arm have the same results? What type of motor is on the Ronin 4D's arm? Also, does anyone have any suggestions on a gimbal that is compact, can hold 15oz, and is easily dissectable?
Thanks for any feedback!